# Reflexivo: Se dativo

Tags: gramática, reflexivos

Could you please explain the below:

> Se dativo o intensificador del verbo.
>   Con el mismo valor: me, te, nos, os.
>   A veces, el pronombre reflexivo sirve únicamente para intensificar el significado del verbo, en construcciones transitivas o intransitivas. Puede añadir matices significativos, no siempre precisos ni claros.
>   Se presenta en dos tipos de construcciones
>
> Concordados: la persona del pronombre coincide con el sujeto:
>   · Comió tres platos. / Se comió tres platos. (Transitiva)
>    *(Here we emphasize what? What tone?)*
>
> · Fue en seguida. / Se fue en seguida. (Intransitiva)
>    *(Here we emphasize what? What tone?)*
>
> No concordados: la persona del pronombre no coincide con el sujeto:
>   · ¡No seas embustero!/¡No me seas embustero!
>    *(Here we emphasize what? What tone?)*

---

Take "Se comió tres platos" as an example. Since "se" is "pronombre dativo", does "se" mean "to himself/herself"? "He/She ate three dishes to himself/herself". Am I correct?
If this is correct, it's very similar to verbo reflexivo.

Answer (score 2):

When we speak about emphasizing I think that it is a bit subjective but I will do my best.

From my point of view:

> Comió tres platos. / Se comió tres platos. (Transitiva)

The first one is simply plain: you inform that someone ate three dishes. The second one emphasizes that someone was able to eat thre dishes, thus trying to remark that he/she could manage to do it.

> Fue en seguida. / Se fue en seguida. (Intransitiva)

The first one is telling that someone left quickly. The second is telling the same but is paying more attention to the fact that he/she made the decision of leaving.

> ¡No seas embustero!/¡No me seas embustero!

The first one is telling someone not to be a liar. The second one tells the same but it is also remarking that he/she (the speaker) does not want that he/she (the referred) tries to lie to me.

**Update**

> Take "Se comió tres platos" as an example. Since "se" is "pronombre dativo", does "se" mean "to himself/herself"? "He/She ate three dishes to himself/herself". Am I correct? If this is correct, it's very similar to verbo reflexivo.

Be careful, "se" is a "prononmbre dativo" for emphasizing the action of the verb. The meaning in "se comió tres platos" is "he/she could manage to eat three dishes", it means that it was a lot of food and he/she did that.

Comment: So does it mean the "se" and "me" in these examples are neither "pronombre acusativo" nor "pronombre dativo" and nor reflexive? They are just for emphasizing the tones?

Comment: In this cases, "se" is a "pronombre dativo", as your text is trying to explain. Moreover, it is used to emphasizing the tone.

Comment: It's difficult to distinguish between the "prononmbre dativo" and "valor factivio", and "se reflexivo". Take "La niña se peina" as an example, it suits all the three functions. How do you distinguish between them?

Comment: @Cadenza, the "peinar" verb is a "reflexivo" verb, like "lavarse los dientes", "enjuagarse la boca", "maquillarse", etc. It is only a matter of practising the language, sometimes there is no a general rule.

Comment: Yes I know that "peinar" is a reflexive verb. But according to the grammar points, we could also say it the "factivio" (she asked her mother to peinar for her) or "pronounbre dativo" for emphasize (she peinar for herself), no?

Comment: @Cadenza, in this case, in my opinion, "peinarse" is only a "reflexive" verb. For me it is difficult to see either the "factitivo" ("peinarse" is normally done on your own) or "dativo" meaning (there is no need to emphasize, the verb is just "reflexivo")

Comment: I dont' agree with you. A child can ask her mother to comb her hair (an order) OR A child can do it herself even she is so small (a emphasize).

Comment: @Cadenza, theoretically, it is like you say, which can open to misinterpretation (is it "dativo"? is it "enfático"?). Practically, the "peinar" verb is a reflexive verb.

Comment: @cadenza Sorry to interfere, as you say the girl can ask her mother to comb her hair but in this case you'd formule the sentece as "La niña pidió a su madre que la peinara" no "se" to discuss about, the reflexive verbs lose the "se" when the subject is not doing the verb on itselfs.

Answer (score 0):

To add to zirrus' answer:

> Fue en seguida. / Se fue en seguida. (Intransitiva)

This form is quite used, and the change of emphasis is well defined. The first form, more plain , implies that he went somewhere (the place might be tacit, but it's asssumed to be known) ("He went at once "). The second form, with "se", disregards this aspect ("where did he go?") and focuses on the subject, to state that he left the place; it's to be translated rather as "He left at once".